# Scrolling Fixed Top Button | CSS & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wanting to recreate the "Proceed to checkout" button on amazon.com. Only trouble is their site isn't responsive nor can I emulate my Chrome browser to show me a device user agent view. You'll need to view the button on your smartphone but here is what I'm wanting to do.

Essentially is to create a scrolling sticky button. When the user hits a page initially they will see a "buy now" button at the bottom of the page / screen. When the user scrolls and the button appears at the top of the page ( due to scrolling ) I want the button to stay there while the user scrolls further down the page. This is for mobile view ( responsive ) only.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fkdLE/25/) of what I have done so far.

I imagine I will need to get the scroll position to apply CSS at the point I want the button to become sticky.

jQuery's `.scrollTop()` method seems to be the best bet.

Comment: Have you tried CSS's `position:fixed;`?

Comment: @PHPglue Yes but it's when to apply the styling... That's the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: Use a condition, like `if($(window).scollTop() === 500){/* do stuff here */}`.

Comment: @PHPglue I have a condition there - it's figuring out the correct scroll point to apply the styling then remove. Are you able to help with a jsfiddle? I've provided what I've done so far in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var bn = $('#bn');
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    bn.css({position:'fixed', bottom:'10px'});
  }
  else{
    bn.css('position', 'static');
  }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fkdLE/51/)

Adjust accordingly. Make sure, as you already have, that your container has a `position:relative;`. If you want it for the whole page set `body{position:relative;}` in your CSS. The `fixed` position will be based on this. `static` is the default position on every Element.